# Google cloud SQL login fails from Tedious

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, tedious

I try to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server hosted in Google Cloud with Tedious 9.2.1 library, but I keep getting this error:

```
Logon failed for login 'sqlserver' due to trigger execution.
```

The code is as follows:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

var config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sqlserver',
            password: 'password',
        },
    },
};

var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err)
    }
    executeStatement();
});
```

I did not set any logon trigger, not even a single saved procedure.

What I tried:

- login with a non-admin user
- restart the database
- recreate the database into a clean state (no users, no tables)

However connecting with Microsoft SSMS, JetBrains DataGrip and .NET application works just fine.

Comment: Hi, did you ever fixed it? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @dev_huesca Google is still working on a fix, as per linked issue below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an opened investigation on this issue:

[Logon failed for login due to trigger execution](https://issuetracker.google.com/170026117)

The Google Cloud Sql Engineering Team is working on solving the issue.

It is well worth to ‘star’ the thread to ensure that you receive updates about it.